# Email Relaying Not Working When email is sent from Apex

Tags: apex, email, singleemailmessage

Our application has a few features where we allow the user to generate documents and send emails. This is all custom lightning components and apex code. We send the emails using `SingleEmailMessage`.

The problem we are having is when our customers setup Email Relaying, it does not seem to work for these custom buttons. When they send emails through the activity tab on records the relaying works.

Has anyone run into this issue?